# How do I make my profile icon use the same image on my google profile?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, profiles, nexus-6p

I'm currently using Nexus 6P with Marshmallow. I have not added other profiles on my device.

Why does my profile icon not share the same image used on my Google account? I recalled this working on an earlier android version (maybe Kitkat or Lollipop) but it only took effect after adding more users. I might be remembering this completely wrong, though.

Is there a way to make the image share what is already on my google profile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is that this is controlled by the google+ app.

[according to this xda thread try:](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/android-5-0-lollipop-user-profile-photo-t2939546)

> 1. Open Setting -> Apps -> All -> Contacts Storage -> Clear Data
> 2. Open Google+ -> Settings -> Your account (under Account Settings) -> Contacts -> Keep contacts up to date

Comment: The more confusing thing to me is why, if I set up a new phone and restore from a backup, is this setting not already set. In fact why do so many apps (even from google) installed during a backup restoration on a new phone activation (or factory reset) act like "O hai new person! Leme explain stuff here"

Comment: I've just restored my Android 7.0 Moto 4G+ and I have the missing profile pic in the quick launch tray thing, but that option to sync contacts is now missing from the version of G+ I have installed! (AFAICT)