# Can't set picture in Android Quick Setting

Tags: nexus-5, google-plus, quick-settings

[image: screenshot of quick settings]

I want my Google Plus profile picture to appear in notifications Quick settings area, Prior to this update it used to work by going to google plus app> settings> contacts > then ticking two options that I can't remember. But those options are gone now.

[image: Screenshot of Google plus settings]

I'm using a custom ROM (which doesn't seem to be an issue)

- Rom I'm using is [DarkRom](https://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/rom-dark-rom-t3492150) caf
- Android 7.1.2 (may security update)
- Based On Lineage 14.1

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134921/how-do-i-make-my-profile-icon-use-the-same-image-on-my-google-profile

Comment: @RahulGopi yes, I used to do exactly that but now, Contacts options isn't available in Google Plus app (at least not at that location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of some version from may, the `contact` option was removed mysterously by google. Maybe they are going to reintroduce it by some other mechanism. But for now, you'll need to download  the g+ app prior to may (you can get legit apks from [apkmirror](http://apkmirror.com)). Then enable the contact sync from that. Post which, you can upgrade to the latest g+ version

Comment: Let me try that out

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the User icon has anything to do with your G+ profile picture. Go to Settings > Users > tap on 'You (Sumeet Deshmukh) > tap on the default blue profile picture to select a new one.

Comment: It's a wrong assumption, it's has much to do with google + profile picture, your way isn't wrong, user icon can be set by your way, but I want my google plus profile picture to be set as user icon. That makes this answer irrelevant here IMHO